# jQuery Datatables in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I used below code & it works fine but I want data in tbody from ng-repeat not from dt-options.

Or is there any way, to change an existing angular table into datatables.

Angular Module:-

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['datatables']);
    app.controller('myCntrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
        function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
            $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("name", "Name"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DOB", "DOB"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("Gender", "Gender"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("Email", "Email ID"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("Mobile", "Mobile"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("Address", "Address"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("JoiningDate", "Joining Date"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DepartmentName", "Department Name"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DesignationName", "Designation Name"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("CountryName", "Country Name"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("StateName", "State Name"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("FilePath", "File Path")
            //,DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("Actions", "Actions")

            ]

            $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
                url: "/myform/getAll",
                type: "POST"
            })
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(5);

        }])
```

HTML:-

```
    <table class="table table-striped" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions"  dt-columns="dtColumns" >
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use ng-repeat, take a look at this.

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay

Comment: I am using the same approach, but not getting tbody. I am getting this on browser console:- "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

Comment: Just confirm that you are including angular js libraries only once.